# Remove a Products from a Cart which was added by a Specific User

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have created a Cart feature in which the products will be added to a cart if user clicks on "Add to Cart" button. The cart item will be stored on a Local Storage. I have created this in react and also using redux. After adding to a cart the data will look like this:

[image]

So from the another user, I have added a same product to a cart and the JSON will look like this:
[image]

So, when I remove the item from the cart from another user, the product removes from the cart from the both users side.
[image]

So how do I remove a specific item from a cart of a specific user?

cart Reducer's code

```
  export const CartReducer = (
    state = { cartItems: [], shippingInfo: {} },
    action
  ) => {
switch (action.type) {
  case ADD_TO_CART:
    const item = action.payload;

    const isItemExist = state.cartItems.find(
      (i) => i.product === item.product
    );

    if (isItemExist) {
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: state.cartItems.map((i) =>
          i.product === isItemExist.product ? item : i
        ),
      };
    } else {
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
      };
    }

  case REMOVE_CART_ITEM:
    return {
      ...state,
      cartItems: state.cartItems.filter((i) => i.product !== action.payload),
    };

  case SAVE_SHIPPING_INFO:
    return {
      ...state,
      shippingInfo: action.payload,
    };

  default:
    return state;
}
```

};

Remove Items from a Cart Action

```
export const removeItemsFromCart = (id,user_id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
dispatch({
  type: REMOVE_CART_ITEM,
  payload: id
});

localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `REMOVE_CART_ITEM` case you should be filtering on both `userId` and `product` if you want to only remove a given product for a specific user.

You could change your case to something like this:

```
case REMOVE_CART_ITEM:
    return {
      ...state,
      cartItems: state.cartItems.filter((i) => !(i.product === action.payload.product && i.user === action.payload.userId)),
    };
```

Your `removeItemsFromCart` would then be:

```
export const removeItemsFromCart = (id, user_id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
   dispatch({
     type: REMOVE_CART_ITEM,
     payload: {
        product: id,
        userId: user_id
     }
   });

   localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
}
```